# Using Python Add-In to delete/remove ArcMap layers that are turned off?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, layers, python-addin

I have made a python addin button which removes layers that are turned off in an MXD.  The strange thing is that I get different results depending on whether I run the python commands in the python window vs my actual addin button.

In my addin class, the code looks like this:

```
def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for layer in layerList:
            if layer.visible == False:
                arcpy.Delete_management(layer)
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

So, this works fine in the python window but doesn't do anything in the button.  I assume because it's trying to delete a layer object instead of the name.  I have made a workaround which changes the following line:

```
arcpy.Delete_management(layer.name)
```

Now this actually works.  But there is a caveat, if I have multiple layers with the same name but different visibility settings, it may delete the one that is visible.  My second workaround is to change the layer name before I delete it.

My final code looks like this:

```
def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for layer in layerList:
            if layer.visible == False:
                layer.name += '_'
                arcpy.Delete_management(layer.name)
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

By changing the name of the layer, I'm ensuring that I only delete invisible layers.  But I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about doing this.

My question is, is there a better way to remove layers that are not visible from an MXD?  Especially when they have the same name?

Comment: You don't want to delete the layer, you want to remove it see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000039000000 This resolves the issue as you supply the layer and the dataframe - no confusion there!

Comment: Of course.  I was looking for the remove function but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to remove the layer using [arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000039000000). The parameters are the [data frame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/) to remove the layer from (possibly a group layer if you are trying to remove from a group) and the [layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) itself, this alleviates any chance of confusion:

```
def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] # assume only one data frame
        layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for layer in layerList:
            if layer.visible == False:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,layer)
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```